# Android java | Suttering and lags when updating View layout params

Tags: java, android, view

Recently I'm making a game which requires continuous animation.

I'll explain it further.

I got view let's say top of the screen and I need to animate it from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen and then it will go back to the original spot (Top of the screen) when the view is on the bottom.

Now there's 6 views which does the exactly same thing.

Animate from top of the screen to the bottom of the screen and back when they are on the bottom.

But when they are already moving there's really annoying stuttering and lags on the application.

Here's the code :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focus) {
    new LongOperation().execute();

}




private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!failedM) {
                        running = true;
                        soundPool.play(click_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

                        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        p1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        p2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        p3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        c1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        c2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        c3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                while (true) {
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(60);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {


                                            p1.getHitRect(rect1);

                                            p2.getHitRect(rect2);

                                            p3.getHitRect(rect3);

                                            c1.getHitRect(rect4);

                                            c2.getHitRect(rect5);

                                            c3.getHitRect(rect6);
                                            if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect1)
                                                     {
                                                .....

                                            }
                                            if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect2)
                                                    ) {

.....
                                            }
                                            if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect3)
                                                    ) {
                                                .....

                                            }
                                            if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect4)
                                                    ) {
                                                .....

                                            }
                                            if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect5)
                                                    ) {
                                                .....

                                            }
                                            if (Rect.intersects(rect, rect6)
                                                    ) {
                                                .....

                                            }


                                            downy1 += 1;
                                            downy2 += 1;
                                            downy3 += 1;
                                            downy4 += 1;
                                            downy5 += 1;
                                            downy6 += 1;

                                            params1.topMargin = params1.topMargin
                                                    + downy1;
                                            params2.topMargin = params2.topMargin
                                                    + downy2;
                                            params3.topMargin = params3.topMargin
                                                    + downy3;
                                            params4.topMargin = params4.topMargin
                                                    + downy4;
                                            params5.topMargin = params5.topMargin
                                                    + downy5;
                                            params6.topMargin = params6.topMargin
                                                    + downy6;
                                            p1.setLayoutParams(params1);
                                            p2.setLayoutParams(params2);
                                            p3.setLayoutParams(params3);
                                            c1.setLayoutParams(params4);
                                            c2.setLayoutParams(params5);
                                            c3.setLayoutParams(params6);
                                            if (p1.getTop() > height) {
                                                downy1 = 0;

                                                params1.leftMargin = newX;
                                                params1.topMargin = orig1y;
                                                p1.setLayoutParams(params1);

                                            }

                                            if (p2.getTop() > height) {
                                                downy2 = 0;

                                                params2.leftMargin = newX;
                                                params2.topMargin = orig2y;
                                                p2.setLayoutParams(params2);

                                            }

                                            if (p3.getTop() > height) {
                                                downy3 = 0;

                                                params3.leftMargin = newX;
                                                params3.topMargin = orig3y;
                                                p3.setLayoutParams(params3);

                                            }

                                            if (c1.getTop() > height
                                                    && !failedM) {
                                                downy4 = 0;

                                                params4.leftMargin = newX;
                                                params4.topMargin = orig4y;
                                                c1.setLayoutParams(params4);
                                            }

                                            if (c2.getTop() > height
                                                    && !failedM) {
                                                downy5 = 0;

                                                params5.leftMargin = newX;
                                                params5.topMargin = orig5y;
                                                c2.setLayoutParams(params5);

                                            }

                                            if (c3.getTop() > height
                                                    && !failedM) {
                                                downy6 = 0;

                                                params6.leftMargin = newX;
                                                params6.topMargin = orig6y;
                                                c3.setLayoutParams(params6);

                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();

                }

            });
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

As you can see there's (if view.getTop() > height)

What it means is that when the view Y is bigger than the height which is when the view is moving from the top to the bottom it will go back to the top.

I hope I made it clear

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using one of the standard animation APIs, like http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views ? Or, if this is a game, why are you not using either the 2D `Canvas` drawing API, OpenGL, or a game framework?

Comment: I found this method easier for me. But the APIs that you are talking about can solve this problem? (Thanks for replying by the way).

Comment: "But the APIs that you are talking about can solve this problem?" -- yes, insofar as trying to force layouts many times a second will not work well, as you are encountering.

Comment: Oh and yes it is a game

Comment: Ok I'll try it out and I'll let you know , thank you in the meanwhile

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm sorry but it didn't Improved my app .Infact it made it worst.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the animation framework. (`view.animate()...`).
Setting layout params requires re-calculating the layout, which is potentially not a cheap operation (depends on your layout).

You can use animation framework or set `translateX/Y` etc properties of the view, which avoid re-calculating the layout.

Comment: Is it Below or approximately API 8?

Comment: Sorry, it is api 12. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html